# Make an array of constant values of the height of a spilled range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following worksheet where `C3#` is a spilled range. I would like to make another spilled range in E3 whose elements are all `"VALUE"`.

I have already given a solution `=IF(ROW(C3#)>0,"VALUE")`. As I use this function very often, does anyone know other alternatives? For instance, how could we build an array of `"VALUE"` of the height of `ROWS(C3#)` (without using LAMBDA-related functions which are still in preview)?

[image]

Comment: that is about simplistic as it gets. If you are not worried about blanks `ROW(C3#)>0` can be replaced with `C3#<>""` but that is only one less character to type and has the disadvantage if you want the value even if the value returned in the first array is blank.

Comment: another option is: `=INDEX({"Value"},SEQUENCE(ROWS(C3#),,1,0))` but again it is not as simplistic as what you have.  Both return an array of `Value` the height of the first array.

Comment: Try SEQUENCE or AGGREGATE functions

Answer (score 2):

If all your values in your dynamic array are numeric (0+) then you can use a simple:

```
=IF(C3#,"VALUE")
```

Otherwise maybe:

```
=IF(C3#=C3#,"VALUE")
```

Or:

```
=LEFT(C3#,0)&"VALUE"
```